# How to delete version into version control of Team Foundation Server 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

I'm a new user into Team Foundation Server and I have a problem, during the develop an desktop app, a team member performed a inestable version and update (realize check-in) this version into the version control and the moment when I check-in my code the server merge my code with the latest version and the system failure.

I decided delete unstable versions of control version, but I not find way perform this.

I read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956.aspx) but in the article only explain how to perform Roll back version and this does not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do a rollback to maintain history of that change.

If you rollback the checkin out is just the same as if you had never checked that code in.

Comment: I need realize check-In including all project ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand that statement. Please explain.

Comment: I try step by step as described in before comment but this not function for my.
I apply Roll Back for my project to stable version and the moment in I realize check-in my new version and the latest version (unstable version) the server realize merge between those versions.
My question is I need upload (check-in) all code of my project ?
Sorry for my ugly way writing my question and thanks for take time for help me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realized RollBack and this solution my problem, I performed RollBack correctly.